# ScrollView scrolling stops once toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE) and I have to scroll again

Tags: android, android-scrollview

ScrollView scrolling stops on **toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE)**. I have to again scroll to continue scrolling but there's no problem with **View.INVISIBLE** but Only text of AppBar goes Invisible. I have also tried **getSupportActionBar().hide();** but same result Below is my code.

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new     ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            int scrollY=scrollView.getScrollY();
            if (scrollY>0){
                fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                if (scrollY>350){
 //Here When scrolling reached to 350 scrolling Stops. I have to Scroll Again. 
                    toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                Log.d("scrollPosition"," "+scrollY);
            }else {
                fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      // I have no problem while scrolling to top.
            }


        }
    });
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.queendevelopers.appalamusicplayer.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Manifest.xml

```
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I am using Android default templete **Android Activity With Navigation Drawer**

Comment: I would recommend animating them out when scrolling and back when not scrolling, this will help: https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling(part1)/

Comment: @BradleyWilson I tried this but doing same function like View.INVISIBLE where only AppName hides but doesn't hides the Appbar

Comment: It is better to use CoordinatorLayout for that porpose: take alook at [link]https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: @Belzebub I will look after this shortly.

Comment: @Belzebub I have tried but same result like before only AppBar Names and 3 horizontal line (Drawer  Indicator) hides, but appBar remains there.